# JOGL + JButton canvas only updated when window is resized

Tags: java, swing, opengl, graphics, jogl

I have been trying to make a simple program which displays a line when a button is pressed, however when I press the button nothing happens, only after I resize the screen, the line gets displayed. Any help would be highly appreciated !

I have noticed that display() gets called only on resizing. I'm using a simple getter-setter class, keylogger, for button pressed events.

```
public class Main implements GLEventListener {

JFrame myframe;
GLCanvas mycanvas;

keyLogger KL = new keyLogger();

@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    gl.glPointSize(4.0f);
    //System.out.println("Dsp");
    //System.out.println(KL.getButton1());

    if(KL.getButton1() == 1) {
        //System.out.println("If");
        //System.out.println(KL.getButton1());
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINES);
        gl.glVertex3f(0.50f, -0.50f, 0);
        gl.glVertex3f(-0.50f, 0.50f, 0);
        gl.glEnd();
        //gl.glFlush();
    }
}

@Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {

}

@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}

@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height){
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glViewport(x, y, width, height);
}

//main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.Canvas();
}

public void Canvas() {
    final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
    GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);

    //
    mycanvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);
    Main mainInstance = new Main();
    mycanvas.addGLEventListener(mainInstance);

    //
    mycanvas.setSize(800, 600);

    //
    mainInstance.makeCanvas(mycanvas);
}

public void makeCanvas(GLCanvas mycanvas) {
    //
    myframe = new JFrame("Paint");
    myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //
    myframe.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mycanvas);

    //
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Button1");
    button1.addActionListener(new button1_listener());
    myframe.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, button1);

    //
    myframe.setSize(myframe.getContentPane().getPreferredSize());
    myframe.setVisible(true);
    //mycanvas.repaint();
}

class button1_listener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        //System.out.println("Lstn");
        //System.out.println(KL.getButton1());
        KL.setButton1(1);

    }
}
```

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: BTW - have you practised getting a line to draw in a custom painted Swing component? If not, I'd recommend doing that before adding the complication of JOGL.. It seems you may have bitten off more than you can chew.

Comment: Where is your animator? Please look at my rudimentary example: https://gist.github.com/gouessej/3420e2b6f632efdddf98#file-joglquad-java-L74